# In which version of the ICD was homosexuality classified as a disease?

Tags: history, icd-intrntl-classif-disea

In Wikipedia article it is said, that [in `ICD-9` homosexuality was listed as a disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homosexuality#Psychology) and that it was removed from there in `ICD-10`.

From third party sources, I knew, that homosexuality was listed under number `302.0` in `ICD-9`.

Unfortunately in ICD-9 service [I see `Ego-dystonic sexual orientation` under this number](http://www.icd9data.com/2012/Volume1/290-319/300-316/302/302.0.htm).

This means person knows his orientation and wishes to change it.

But this is not what "homosexuality" means (sexual affection directed to same-sex partners).

So, the question is: was homosexuality itself ever classified as a disease and when it was?

Answer (score 6):

I should look at the actions of American Psychiatric Assocation (APA) ([1](http://roundtable.menloschool.org/issue10/3_Taylor_MS_Roundtable10_Fall_2011.pdf)).

> Although American homosexuals today are still struggling for equal
>   rights, no shift has been more drastically beneficial for the status
>   of homosexuality than its declassification as a mental illness. The
>   American Psychiatric Association’s Board of Trustees passed this
>   groundbreaking decision unanimously on December 15, 1973, and
>   subsequently released  a statement that rejected legal discrimination
>   on the basis of sexual  orientation. In the publication of its
>   monumental decision to remove  homosexuality from the Diagnostic and
>   Statistical Manual of Mental  Disorders (DSM), the board cited “review
>   of evidence[,]...changing  social norms and growing gay-rights
>   activism.”

And indeed, Medicine has a dark history when homosexuality was regarded as mental illness.

[Classification of diseases as adopted by the Massachusetts General Hospital (1919)](http://collections.nlm.nih.gov/catalog/nlm:nlmuid-26520130R-bk)

[image]

In the [military medicine](http://collections.nlm.nih.gov/catalog/nlm:nlmuid-58010590R-bk) in the year 1949 homosexuality was classified under "psychopathy".

[image]

[A "modern" perspective](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL5604593M/Noyes'_modern_clinical_psychiatry.) in 1968 was to consider pedophilia as a subtype of homosexuality.

[image]

Another ["modern" perspective](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL5704106M/Modern_perspectives_in_world_psychiatry.) in 1971 considered LSD as a "treatment" for homosexuality.

[image]

So, yes, things were slightly different back in the days.